# How can I broaden a caption?

Tags: captions, width

I’m trying to extend a caption beyond `\textwidth`. I tried it with `\makebox`, however, that resuls in an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}ccc@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}&
        \includegraphics[width=0.31\linewidth,height=2cm]{dummy}
\end{tabular*}
\makebox[1.2\textwidth][c]{
\caption{\emph{Title.} \blindtext}
}
\label{fig:mipLevels}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
Missing \endgroup inserted.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to locally change the `width`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,caption,showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \captionsetup{width=1.2\textwidth}
  \caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Horizontal adjustment using the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage)'s `adjustwidth` environment is also an option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage,blindtext,showframe}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  % Add .1\textwidth on either side of the caption
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-.1\textwidth}{-.1\textwidth}
    \caption{\blindtext}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Werner says caption package has some specific parameters for this, or as with any text 
you can just use an environment like `quote` but with negative margins. This can be useful if you also need to make the other text wider, not just the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{outdent}
               {\list{}{\leftmargin-2cm
                \rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

X\dotfill X

\caption{%
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
}

\begin{quote}
\caption{%
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
}
\end{quote}

\begin{outdent}
\caption{%
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a  a a a a a a a
}
\end{outdent}


\end{table} 


\end{document}
```